# I'm Trying to Show Progress With MBProgressHUD using MWFeedParser

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, progress-bar, mbprogresshud

Hello I've been trying to display progress using the annular determinate for the last hour and I can't seem to make it do what I want. It either disappears way before my table view is loaded with content or never loads to progress bar fully.

In my viewDidLoad method I show it while starting to run MWFeedParser like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

// Parse
NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com"];
feedParser = [[MWFeedParser alloc] initWithFeedURL:feedURL];
feedParser.delegate = self;
feedParser.feedParseType = ParseTypeFull; // Parse feed info and all items
feedParser.connectionType = ConnectionTypeAsynchronously;
[feedParser parse];

// Display HUD
[super viewDidLoad];

HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
HUD.labelText = @"Loading";
HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Just relax";
HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
[self.view addSubview:HUD];

[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(feedParserDidStart:) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];

}
```

After I call my parser it then runs through 5 different steps, I want to update my HUD as it goes through these steps, but I can't seem to do that. The next steps are these:

```
- (void)feedParserDidStart:(MWFeedParser *)parser {
NSLog(@"Started Parsing: %@", parser.url);

float stepsDone = 0.20;    
HUD.progress = stepsDone;

}

- (void)feedParser:(MWFeedParser *)parser didParseFeedInfo:(MWFeedInfo *)info {
NSLog(@"Parsed Feed Info: “%@”", info.title);

float stepsDone = 0.40;    
HUD.progress = stepsDone;


}

- (void)feedParser:(MWFeedParser *)parser didParseFeedItem:(MWFeedItem *)item {
NSLog(@"Parsed Feed Item: “%@”", item.title);
if (item) [parsedItems addObject:item]; 

float stepsDone = 0.60;    
HUD.progress = stepsDone;
}

- (void)feedParserDidFinish:(MWFeedParser *)parser {
NSLog(@"Finished Parsing%@", (parser.stopped ? @" (Stopped)" : @""));
[self updateTableWithParsedItems];

float stepsDone = 0.80;    
HUD.progress = stepsDone;
}

- (void)feedParser:(MWFeedParser *)parser didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"Finished Parsing With Error: %@", error);
if (parsedItems.count == 0) {
    // Failed but some items parsed, so show and inform of error

}

//Update Table
[self updateTableWithParsedItems];
}

- (void)updateTableWithParsedItems {
self.itemsToDisplay = [parsedItems sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                       [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" 
                                                                            ascending:NO] ]];
self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.tableView.alpha = 1;
[self.tableView reloadData];

float stepsDone = 1.0;    
HUD.progress = stepsDone;

[HUD hide:YES afterDelay:1];
}
```

I would appreciate any help! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)** will help you out along with a good example.

Comment: thank you, but I've looked over that and the example doesn't quite tell me how to update the progress bar. Seeing that I'm new to progress bars I don't know how to update it based on my needs, and the example only uses a loop.

Answer (score 6):

I think i got answer for Year3000

```
self.HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
[self.view addSubview:self.HUD];
self.HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminateHorizontalBar;
self.HUD.delegate = self;
[self.HUD show:YES];
```

//catch your progress and set it to HUD

```
- (void)Uploadprogress:(float)progress
{
    self.HUD.progress = progress;
}
```

This works for me

Answer (score 2):

MBProgressHUDMode**AnnularDeterminate** !

```
MBProgressHUD * hud = [MBProgressHUD HUDForView:self.view];

hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate
```

then update your hud value: *(values 0.0 to 1.0)*

```
- (void)Uploadprogress:(float)progress
{
    self.HUD.progress = progress;
}
```